# Автоматизировать клик для Ajax-запроса

Tags: ajax, php

Доброго.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    function update(){
                        $(".buttonUpload").click(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                url:"ajax.php",
                                type:"POST",
                                cache:true,
                                data: "id="+$(this).attr("value"),
                                success: function(html){
                                    $("#category_tray_one").html(html);
                                    update();
                                }
                            })
                        });
                    }
                    update();
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="category_tray_one" class="">
                <div id="super_id_101" class="buttonUpload" value="101">101</div>
                <div id="super_id_115" class="buttonUpload" value="115">115</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Собственно, код выше, по нему описание и вопрос. Вот мы клинкули, и в ajax.php ушло скромное [id] => 110 или [id] => 115

Допустим, я знаю, что мне нужно послать в ajax.php `data: "id=125"`, не нажимая на странице. Собственно, как это сделать? (Самому в голову ничего не пришло.)

Comment: 1) переписать код (параметры в ajax запросе)

2) создать элемент div с value = 125, повесить на него update, вызвать у него click() и удалить

Comment: Странная у вас конструкция, не понятно, что для чего нужна функция update(), события клик не нужно дополнительно активировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда просто уберите клик

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    function update(){
                            $.ajax({
                                url:"ajax.php",
                                type:"POST",
                                cache:true,
                                data: "id=115"),
                                success: function(html){
                                    $("#category_tray_one").html(html);
                                    update();
                                }
                            })
                    }
                    update();
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Это гениально! Писал отдельный скрипт для этого. Чуть с ума не сошел )

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не выделить кусок кода, непосредственно посылающий данные, в отдельную функцию, принимающую в качестве параметра значение, которое нужно послать, и колбэк для обработки ответа?

```
function sendData(value, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        cache:true,
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
}

$(".buttonUpload").click(function(){
    sendData("id="+$(this).attr("value"), function(html){
        $("#category_tray_one").html(html);
        update();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[[@Diefair](/users/23971/diefair)](/users/23971/diefair) правильно написал, нужно убрать клик, но нужно ещё и передавать в функцию id, и уберите рекурсию из success:

```
function update(id){
   $.ajax({
     url:"ajax.php",
     type:"POST",
     cache:true,
     data: "id="+id,
     success: function(html){
        $("#category_tray_one").html(html);
     }
   });
};
update(125);
```